# How can I find not same data using mysql regexp in multiline text?

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-regexp

I tried to find the data using regexp in multiline text.
My regexp is 'Audit Policy,[A-Za-z0-9|[:space:]]+,Success and Failure'.

```
# query
SELECT *
  FROM docs
 WHERE content not regexp 'Audit Policy,[A-Za-z0-9|[:space:]]+,Success and Failure';

# data
'Audit Policy,Audit account logon events,No Auditing
Audit Policy,Audit account management,Success and Failure
Audit Policy,Audit logon events,No Auditing
Audit Policy,Audit object access,Success and Failure'
```

I think I can search the whole data included in 'Audit Policy,Audit logon events,No Auditing' when I run the below code but it's not that work.
Is there a way to get that line only using SQL queries?

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8adc4b/2

My sql version is 5.7.25 / the data column type is varchar.

Comment: What is the problem statement here?  What are you trying to match or extract?

Comment: What do you mean by "not same data"?

Comment: Are you trying to split up the text into lines, and return the lines that don't match the regexp? I don't think there's any easy way to do that in MySQL. The regexp is being matched against the entire string. You should normalize your data and put each line into a separate row of the table.

Comment: @Barmar I think when I run the script, I can get contets because I run "not regexp". Thank you for your advice. It might be difficult to get what I want if I don't separate rows of the data in the table.

Comment: Your regex seems fine, your table only contains one row so you do not get the right output. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51733f/1)